# Xml and Java coding not Build Properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Yesterday, I downloaded a Project which was in eclipse and i imported it in my android studio may be due to this or some other reason today when i opened my android studio recent projects it was showing error in gradle file with some other language i searched for the error which was "File was Loaded in Wrong Encoding UTF-8 " and got a method to change from file

Please help me out what should i do i tried searching every where but could not get a fine result which worked for me.

Here is my sample code of .xml file which is don't know in which format and why

```
����   3
  0abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark I 
ConstantValue   1abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light  (abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material  abc_btn_colored_text_material  abc_color_highlight_material  !abc_hint_foreground_material_dark  "abc_hint_foreground_material_light  !abc_input_method_navigation_guard  +abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark  ,abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_light     abc_primary_text_material_dark 
 abc_primary_text_material_light  abc_search_url_text  abc_search_url_text_normal 
 abc_search_url_text_pressed  abc_search_url_text_selected   abc_secondary_text_material_dark  !abc_secondary_text_material_light  abc_tint_btn_checkable  abc_tint_default  abc_tint_edittext  abc_tint_seek_thumb  abc_tint_spinner  abc_tint_switch_track  accent_material_dark  accent_material_light  !background_floating_material_dark  "background_floating_material_light  background_material_dark  background_material_light  (bright_foreground_disabled_material_dark  )bright_foreground_disabled_material_light  'bright_foreground_inverse_material_dark   (bright_foreground_inverse_material_light ! bright_foreground_material_dark "  bright_foreground_material_light # button_material_dark $ button_material_light % cardview_dark_background & cardview_light_background ' cardview_shadow_end_color ( cardview_shadow_start_color ) colorAccent * colorPrimary + colorPrimaryDark , %design_bottom_navigation_shadow_color - design_default_color_primary . !design_default_color_primary_dark / design_error 0 design_fab_shadow_end_color 1 design_fab_shadow_mid_color 2 design_fab_shadow_start_color 3 !design_fab_stroke_end_inner_color 4 !design_fab_stroke_end_outer_color 5 !design_fab_stroke_top_inner_color 6 !design_fab_stroke_top_outer_color 7
```

It was a Fine Working Projects and every thing was working but dnt know what happned tried to reset that was also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searched Alot Tried to make Sdk Locations Update Updated Gradle due to which all my class files were back to normal form but this Xml File was Not re-formatted So At last i created a new Xml File.
But After Some search i come to a result that it might me due to Unwanted Closer of my Android Studio Or may be my battery drained due to which my Android Studio doesn't Closed Properly.

If Any One Know After Every update i can do one more thing so that i can re-arranged my xml file to original format I will Update My Answer if that Worked For me

Thank You.